# Problem binding Mootools events and calling class methods

Tags: javascript, mootools, raphael

What i'm trying to do is a combination of a mootools class and raphael. The problem i got is mainly mootools event binding i guess. 
I'm trying to append an event to a raphael element (dom node) and when firing the event another class method should be called.
This is no problem when coding without a mootools class. But this (the right) way i have some problems. When binding the events, the raphael element cannot be longer used because "this" now refers to the mootools class.

Please take a look at this code and i guess you will understand what my problem is:

```
    // mootools class 
    var test = new Class({

    ...

        initPlane: function() {

            // just an JSON object array
            this.objects = [{"pid":"2","sx":"685","sy":"498","dx":"190","dy":"540"},{"pid":"3","sx":"156","sy":"341","dx":"691","dy":"500"}]; 

            // place the objects on stage and append some events to them
            this.objects.each(function(item, idx){                      
                item.gfx = this.gfx.image("assets/img/enemy.png", item.sx, item.sy, 32, 32);


                // #### differnt approaches to bind the events. all not working

                // first attempt with mootools event
                item.gfx.node.addEvent('click', function(e) {
                    console.log(this.attr('x'));    // not working because this is bound to the class i guess
                    this.info();
                }.bind(this));          

                // second attempt with mootools event
                item.gfx.node.addEvent('click', function(e) {
                    console.log(this.attr('x'));    // not working
                    parent.info(this);              // no binding and not working
                });         

                // first attempt with raphael event
                item.gfx.click( function(e) {
                    console.log(this.attr('x'));    // works !
                    this.info(this);                // not working because this refers to raphael element. 
                });         



            }.bind(this))

        },


        // this method should be called after click event and output element attribs
        info: function(event) {
            console.log(event.attr('x'));
        },      

    ...

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your .each is wrong.

```
Object.each(obj, function(el, key, obj) {

}, bind);
```

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Object#Object:Object-each

although you actually have this.objects as array, did not notice :)

```
Array.each(function(el, index) {

}, bind);
```

when you need `this` to be bound to element on click, that's fine. just store a copy of `this` into `self` and call `self.info()` instead. alternatively, keep the bind and reference `e.target` as the trigger element instead, whilst `this` is your instance

although it may seem 'neater' to try to keep `this` bound to the class wherever possible, mootools-core devs tend to prefer the `var self = this;` way as it avoids the extra callback to bind etc (look at the mootools source, very common)

also, say you want to have the click event go to a method directly:

`element.addEvent("click", this.info.bind(this));`

which will send the event as the 1st argument to info (so reference event.target).

Comment: The foreach works for me. I actually only had this to do: `item.gfx.node.addEvent('click', this.info.bind(this, item));`

Answer (score 1):

`bind` can usually apply arguments as well as the scope (depending on the implementation), and that allows you to write `function (raphaelObj, node) { ... }.bind(null, this, item.gfx.node)` to bind two arguments.

Comment: If the `bind` you're using doesn't allow that, you may want to consider upgrading to one that does :-), for instance https://github.com/Raevel/Cactus/blob/master/lib/Addon/Function.js#L81